# jenkins never finish build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins build never finish, when I restart it, the Console Output shows the following error:

```
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.scm.SCM.getDescriptor(SCM.java:653)
    at hudson.scm.AutoBrowserHolder.get(AutoBrowserHolder.java:54)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.getEffectiveBrowser(SCM.java:136)
    at hudson.scm.ChangeLogParser.parse(ChangeLogParser.java:57)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calcChangeSet(AbstractBuild.java:927)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getChangeSet(AbstractBuild.java:895)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:349)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:672)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Jenkins has not been started, or was already shut down
```

..

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use Maven? Have you upgraded Jenkins/plugin recently?

Comment: I uninstalled some plugins that I installed by mistake and now Jenkins is working again without this mistake. thanks

Comment: I thought the issue was fixed. I didn't update jenkins to the new version of Jenkins 1.653.   I use jenkins to run E2E test in protractor. Any advice?

Comment: NullPointerException happens due to multiple reasons so not sure of the exact cause for your case unless we see the stacktrace of the error.